# Discord.py bot | bot.latency returns nan despite of float

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have a problem with bot.latency in my ping command.

Firstly first, I have declared my bot instance like this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(

description='Genos Bot Help Section - prefix: ^ ', 
command_prefix='^', 
case_insensitive=True, 
guild_subscriptions=True, 
intents=intents

) # I have this in one line in my program, but I wrote it like that in order to be easily read.
```

After that I put my ping command:

```
# I used commands.command because I have cogs for my discord bot.

@commands.command(name="ping")
  async def ping(self, ctx: commands.Context):
     """Ping command!"""
     await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(bot.latency * 1000)} ms')
```

The problem with `bot.latency` is that it return `nan` despite of `float` how it's written in documentation and it cannot made the conversion giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `NaN` is a value of type `float`. It stands for "not a number". You have to check first if it is a valid number before converting it to int.

Comment: The thing is that when I print in console `bot.latency` it gives me `NaN` despite of the latency and this is what I don't understand =(

Comment: Nothing you can do there. Ask the library owner what is going on. It may be fully intended on his side. Either way you still need to check against whether the value is `NaN` or not before multiplying it with a number.

Comment: Did multiply it with a number, still `NaN`. It's funny because on another bot it works, but at this one it doesn't.

Comment: Finally I discovered the fact that If i put my ping command on my index.py it's working, but when I want to add it as a command in cogs, it doesn't work ... returning `NaN` .. Is there any solution to overcome this? @TinNguyen

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix!

Because you are using cogs, `self` is required.

This should fix your problem:

```
await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(self.bot.latency * 1000)} ms')
```

Whole code:

```
@commands.command(name="ping")
  async def ping(self, ctx: commands.Context):
     """Ping command!"""
     await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(self.bot.latency * 1000)} ms')
```